# Uncertain arguments in tf.mul and tf.sqrt

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to get into `Tensorflow` basics with the help of some git examples and tutorials, but i'm stuck on the part where I can't plot a `Gaussian Distribution` graph here is what i did.

```
x = tf.lin_space(-3.0, 3.0, 32)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

s = 0
mean = 0
gauss = (tf.exp(tf.negative(tf.pow(x - mean, 2) / (2 * tf.pow(s, 2)))) * (1.0 / (s * tf.sqrt(2 * 3.1415))))
plt.plot(x.eval(), gauss.eval())
plt.show()
```

i was getting `TypeError` initially because of the float arguments i.e. 2.0 instead of 2 in `tf.pow()` I even tried changing the type but `tf.to_float()` but that didn't helped either and here i am with.

```
ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype int32: 'Tensor("mul:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)'
```

*just a guess* shouldn't there be `tf.matmul` instead of `(2 * tf.pow(s, 2))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem. The input to pow() should be a float. Therefore, **s** should be a float.

```
x = tf.lin_space(-3.0, 3.0, 32)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

s = 1.0 # need to be a float
mean = 0
gauss = (tf.exp(tf.negative(tf.pow(x - mean, 2) / (2 * tf.pow(s, 2)))) * (1.0 / (s * tf.sqrt(2 * 3.1415))))
plt.plot(x.eval(), gauss.eval())
plt.show()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, but the graph doesn't show up anything, any help with that?

Comment: I guess s should be equal to 1 since you are calculating values related to a Gaussian distribution. In your code, s=0.0, because of that Gaussian variable gives  'nan'. That's the reason for not showing the graph